# Finding where code is generated from in a wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress

I'm working with DIVI, and I need to find where a specific div (or two) is being generated from so that I can add another div to contain the elements that follow.

The div that I want to follow up is .et_pb_image_container. features a lot in blog.php, but when I add test classes, they do not show up in the DOM.

I have also tried 3 different plugins which claim to indicate which page code is generated from, but they only say page.php which only contains the outer containers for the pages.

Perhaps this code could hint at where else to look?

```
$this->custom_css_options = array(
        'title' => array(
            'label'    => esc_html__( 'Title', 'et_builder' ),
            'selector' => '.entry-title',
        ),
        'post_meta' => array(
            'label'    => esc_html__( 'Post Meta', 'et_builder' ),
            'selector' => '.post-meta',
        ),
        'pagenavi' => array(
            'label'    => esc_html__( 'Pagenavi', 'et_builder' ),
            'selector' => '.wp_pagenavi',
        ),
        'featured_image' => array(
            'label'    => esc_html__( 'Featured Image', 'et_builder' ),
            'selector' => '**.et_pb_image_container**',
        ),
        'read_more' => array(
            'label'    => esc_html__( 'Read More Button', 'et_builder' ),
            'selector' => '.more-link',
```

Answer (score 0):

It's generated in the file main-modules.php around line 15017

```
elseif ( '' !== $thumb && 'on' === $show_thumbnail ) :
        if ( 'on' !== $fullwidth ) echo '<div class="et_pb_image_container">'; ?>
            <a href="<?php esc_url( the_permalink() ); ?>" class="entry-featured-image-url">
                <?php print_thumbnail( $thumb, $thumbnail["use_timthumb"], $titletext, $width, $height ); ?>
                <?php if ( 'on' === $use_overlay ) {
                    echo $overlay_output;
                } ?>
            </a>
    <?php
        if ( 'on' !== $fullwidth ) echo '</div> <!-- .et_pb_image_container -->';
    endif;
} ?>
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for the response, but my copy of that file only contains 26 lines about firing modules.

Comment: What version of Divi are you using?

Comment: 3.0.85. The file is located here Divi/includes/builder/main-modules.php

Comment: There should be 23k lines of code in the file \Divi\includes\builder\main-modules.php  The part you are interested in is around line 15017

Comment: What you're saying sounds plausible but the code you're referring to isn't in that file. Maybe I'll find it elsewhere. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It's most certainly there, you can find it using Notepad++ search.  I've attached a screenshot showing it.  https://imageshack.com/i/pmMJDjyVp